# activity indicator in tabbar app

Tags: iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a TabBar app that displays a a `uitableview` on startup. The `tableview` data is accessed by a file that is stored in the documents directory of the app.  The data file is quiet big (60MB). For the first time and only in certain devices (3G) it takes too long to write to the directory and iOS kills the app.

I would like to add an activity indicator while writing this file to the directory but have no clue where I should put it.  Should I load a view controller at start up and then dismiss it when the writing of the file is done?  Also, I have no clue how to load this controller and then dismiss it and load my actual `tableview`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not 100% and therefore don't consider this an answer. But WatchDog is killing your app for taking too long to respond and adding an activity indicator is not going to prevent this from happening. You should look into solving your core problem - a 60MB data file. Can it be put into a local store instead of a document?

Comment: no it can't. i wish it could. i ll probably no support 3G devices as this is the only device this is happening. (by the way jb devices do not share this problem, do they disable the watchdog?)

Comment: Maybe you should start your app, and display it will take time, then start the copy in a background thread, and reload the tableview when it's finished. I guess the watchDog won't kill your app, since the MainThread is responding.

Answer (score 1):

dispatch the work into the background

```
dispatch_queue_t background_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.your.rdns.notation", NULL);
dispatch_async(background_queue, ^ {
  //do your work here...

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    //notify the ui here, when your task is done...
  });
});
```

Also there are quite a few good WWDC sessions [WWDC10](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) - definitely worth a look!

cheers

Ron